# Resource handler returned message: "Unable to validate the following destination configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I am trying to send notification on file creating in s3 to SQS.

I am still getting Resource handler returned message: "Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: S3, Status Code: 400) error.

My code is:

```
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    DependsOn:
      - QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub '${AWS::AccountId}-bucket'
      NotificationConfiguration:
        QueueConfigurations:
          - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            Queue: !GetAtt Queue.Arn

  QueuePolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy'
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: "s3.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - 'SQS:SendMessage'
            Resource: !GetAtt Queue.Arn
            Condition:
              ArnLike:
                aws:SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${AWS::AccountId}-bucket'
              StringEquals:
                aws:SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      Queues:
        - !Ref Queue

  Queue:
    Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    Properties:
      DelaySeconds: 0
      KmsMasterKeyId: alias/aws/sqs
      KmsDataKeyReusePeriodSeconds: 300
      QueueName: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}-queue"
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 0
      VisibilityTimeout: !Ref SQSVisibilityTimeout
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 3600
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - "queueDLQ"
            - "Arn"
        maxReceiveCount: 3
```

found example here https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-patterns/blob/main/s3-sqs/template.yaml but I can not make it work. What am I missing?